# scipy.mstats.theilslopes error in confidence limit if data have missing values

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

If one uses the scipy.mstats.theilslopes routine on a data set with missing values, the results of the lower and upper bounds for the slope estimate are incorrect. The upper bound is often/always(?) NaN, while the lower bound is simply wrong. This happens, because the theilslopes routine computes an index into the sorted slopes array, and this array contains slopes of missing values when it shouldn't.

The solution is to remove missing values before analysis, but this is nowhere documented.

To demonstrate the problem, here is a simple code snippet:
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import mstats

```
x = np.arange(12)
y = np.array([28.9, 26.2, 27.2, 26.5, 28.4, 25.3, 26.1, 24.8, 27.7,
              np.nan, np.nan, 29.6])

slope, intercept, lo_slope, up_slope = mstats.theilslopes(y, x,
                                                          alpha=0.1)
print "incorrect: ", slope, lo_slope, up_slope

idx = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11]
x = x[idx]   # equivalent to pandas series.dropna()
y = y[idx]

slope, intercept, lo_slope, up_slope = mstats.theilslopes(y, x,
                                                          alpha=0.1)
print "correct: ", slope, lo_slope, up_slope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`mstats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.mstats.html) module of `scipy.stats`, "missing values" are handled using a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).  `nan` does not indicate a missing value.

The following shows how you can convert your array `y` (which uses `nan` for missing values) into a masked array `my`:

```
In [48]: x = np.arange(12)

In [49]: y = np.array([28.9, 26.2, 27.2, 26.5, 28.4, 25.3, 26.1, 24.8, 27.7, np.nan, np.nan, 29.6])

In [50]: my = np.ma.masked_array(y, mask=np.isnan(y))

In [51]: my
Out[51]: 
masked_array(data = [28.9 26.2 27.2 26.5 28.4 25.3 26.1 24.8 27.7 -- -- 29.6],
             mask = [False False False False False False False False False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [52]: slope, intercept, lo_slope, up_slope = mstats.theilslopes(my, x, alpha=0.1)

In [53]: print "correct: ", slope, lo_slope, up_slope
correct:  -0.125 -0.48 0.3875
```

---

By the way, be sure you are using at least version 0.15.0 of scipy.  `theilslopes` in older versions has some bugs: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3574